# Ably Pub/Sub Realtime ILoggerSink LogEvent not working

Tags: ably-realtime

I am using VB.NET with Ably .NET Realtime library version 1.2.1.  I have a wrapper class setting up and managing Ably.  The class implements ILoggerSink.  It is setting up the channel as shown by these snippets from different parts of the class:

```
Public Class Ably
    Implements IDisposable, ILoggerSink
.
.
Private WithEvents mChannel As IRealtimeChannel
Private Delegate Sub ReceiveMessageDelegate(ByVal m As Message)
Private Delegate Sub PublishCallbackDelegate(ByVal result As Boolean, ByVal einfo As ErrorInfo)
Private mPublishCallbackDelegate As PublishCallbackDelegate = AddressOf PublishCallback
Private mReceiveMessageDelegate As ReceiveMessageDelegate = AddressOf ReceiveMessage
.
.
Dim opt = New ClientOptions(Main.AblyConnectionKey) With {.EchoMessages = False, .LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug}
Dim art = New AblyRealtime(opt)
mChannel = art.Channels.Get(idstr)
mChannel.Subscribe(Sub(m) mReceiveMessageDelegate(m))
.
.
mChannel.Publish(mname, mdata, Sub(m, n) mPublishCallbackDelegate(m, n))
```

The interface method starts with this definition:

```
Public Sub LogEvent(level As LogLevel, message As String) Implements ILoggerSink.LogEvent
'The rest of the sub here.
```

All of the other Ably things managed by this class work - attaching to the channel, publishing messages and receiving messages.  The class gets mChannel.StateChanged and mChannel.[Error] events.

The LogEvent method never gets called.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Update: The accepted answer worked and was a simple thing I missed seeing in any documentation.  Here is the corrected line of code:

```
Dim opt = New ClientOptions(Main.AblyConnectionKey) With {.EchoMessages = False, .LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug, .LogHander = Me}
```

Also deemed noteworthy is that this class is a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece is that you need to tell the library which `LoggerSink` to use.

Something like `Logger.LoggerSink = Me`.

You need to be careful because the ably `Logger` is static and there is only once instance for the whole program. It will be a problem if you are going to instantiate more than one instance of you `Ably` class.

Generally it's recommended to have 1 instance of the RealtimeClient anyway so you will probably be Ok with the above code.